# Set div as background of other div

Tags: javascript, html

We have two `div`s. `divOne` contains information of image and `divTwo` contains information of table. Is it possible that we can set divOne as background image of `divTwo` using script?

```
divOne.innerHTML = <IMG src="http://sbc.com/xyz.jpg" />

divTwo.innerHTML = <TABLE id="content"> ....... </TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`divOne.style.backgroundImage="url(http://sbc.com/xyz.jpg);";`

That should set divOne to that background image...

---

For the div Positioning give this a try...

```
divOne.style.position = "relative";
divOne.style.top = "0px";
divOne.style.left = "0px";
divOne.style.zIndex="1";

divTwo.style.position = "relative";
divTwo.style.top = "0px";
divTwo.style.left = "0px";
divTwo.style.zIndex="2";
```

Comment: That is assuming you are doing this... <div id="divOne"><div id="divTwo"></div></div>

Comment: Thanks for your response. We have url inside div which is generated dynamically. Right now, we are doing divOne.appendChild(div2) but this display first div and then below it second div. We want to display first div as background of second div. Thanks again.

Comment: divOne.style.position = "relative";
divOne.style.top = "0px";
divOne.style.left = "0px";
divOne.style.zIndex="1";

divTwo.style.position = "relative";
divTwo.style.top = "0px";
divTwo.style.left = "0px";
divTwo.style.zIndex="2";

Comment: Thanks for your response but not working. DivOne (background image) disappeared.

Comment: can you post some of your code so it will be easier to give an exact solution? is divTwo transparent?

divTwo.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";

I think that might fix it...

Comment: Thanks for you response. Removed -  divOne.style.top = "0px"; divOne.style.left = "0px";  divTwo.style.top = "0px"; divTwo.style.left = "0px";  and changed divOne.style.position = "absolute"; divTwo.style.position = "absolute". It worked. Thanks again for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - depending on what you mean.

You can position one DIV over another using relative positions and z-index. If the top index is transparent (no background) then you should be able to see through to the one behind it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We are thinking the same but unable to find any example. Any help?